# Find any open, but not closed HTML tags with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all, truncate

OK, first of all, I do not want to parse HTML with RegEx. Or at least that is not my general purpose. The problem is as follows:
I have different language files with different string variables in them (don't mind the encoding, the problem in that particular case is solved). Some of the variables I want to shorten to a particular length, have HTML formatting which I want to keep (e.g. font, h1, strong, a, etc. Sounds like a standard situation, which has already been solved but I face a big problem solving it myself). If you're still reading, Congratulations! My approach to the problem is quite different, I run a while loop, going thru the whole text and counting all the characters outside of `<` and `>`. Here is the code:

```
function shorten($text, $length = 1000, $ellipsis= '...', $html = true) {
    $tagsUsed = array('font', 'b', 'a', 'sub', 'sup');
    $xhtmlTags = array('br');
    $openTags = array();
    $closedTags = array();
    $inTag = false;
    $tagName = "";

    $i = 0;
    $cntr = 0;

    $truncatedStr = "";

    while($cntr < $length){
    $truncatedStr .= $text[$i];

        switch($text[$i]){

            case "<":
                $inTag = true;
                break;

            case ">":
                $inTag = false;
                break;

            default: 
                if($inTag == false){
                    $cntr++;
                }
        }

        $i++;
    }

    preg_match_all("/(<\/?([\w+]+)[^>]*>)?([^<>]*)/", $truncatedStr, $tags);

    foreach ($tags[2] as $tag) {
        if(!in_array($tag, $xhtmlTags)){
            array_push($openTags, $tag);
        }
    }

    return $truncatedStr.$ellipsis;
}
```

And everything works pretty good. Our translation team knows which html tags to use, which is the most important part: This has nothing to do with users posting html, we want to sanitize. The problem comes in the `preg_match_all()` function. I need a regex pattern that will take only the opening part of a tag (e.g. will take `<font>` but will not take `</font>`). Any help is appreciated, and please don't swear very much because of the whole "regex-html" thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've read your question correctly, the regex you want is `<([^/>]+|br\s*\/)>`. To break it down:

`<` matches the literal left-angle character.

`(` creates a group (capturing group in this case, but it doesn't matter too much).

`[^/>]` is a negated character class that will match any character BUT the forward slash or ending angle character.

`+` will match the previous token (the negated character class) repeated one or more times.

`|` acts like boolean OR: match this pattern OR this pattern. In this case, match either the left expression (non-slash repeated) or the right expression (the `br/`).

`br` matches the literal string "br".

`\s` matches any whitespace character.

`*` matches the previous token (whitespace) 0 or more times.

`\/` matches the literal forward-slash character.

`)` closes out the group.

`>` matches the literal right-angle character.

Et voila! `<([^/>]+|br\s*\/)>` matches `<font>` but not `</font>`, `<h1>` but not `</h1>`, and also `<br />`. (Thanks to klaar for pointing that last one out).

Comment: But what about <br/>? Technically that's XHTML, so you are covered, but still.

Comment: `<br>` (with optional `/` for the XML addicted), `<img>`, `<meta>`, `<link>`, `<p>` and many other elements can or must have a start tag but no end tag and still be properly closed.

Comment: @Quentin: if OP only cares about the tags and not for the contents of the tags, then that will not pose a problem. However, if he does... Madness!

Comment: I don't really :) Moreover, I have a separate array() for the xhtml tags. They doesn't bother me, because they cannot "stay open" after the shortening.

Comment: But that pattern doesn't return anything. And I have no idea why. I am a real noob when it comes to regex, so excuse me, please, but the $tags variable is empty.

Comment: The pattern I gave you assumes that each token is being operated on separately. There's only one capture group, which will spit out whatever's in the tag (which I'm assuming is what you want in `$tags`). What is `$truncatedString` for?

Comment: $truncatedStr is the variable that already contains the particular number of characters (and HTML tags). the preg_match_all() function comes after I took the needed number of characters and is used to find which the open tags are, so I could close them :)